# Plotting a label from an Array within Pinescript v5

Tags: arrays, label, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have this code that works well for Pinescript v5, but I am having trouble getting it to plot a label.

So what it does is it pulls technical data from the close of the data, then comapres it with previous technical data over the last say, 500 days, within a specified range, to identify similar days that had similar technicals and give you the average range for those days.

The indicator works great, the issue I am experiencing is, I would like it to plot a label above each of the identified days with the range for that day. This is the area in question:

```
for i = 0 to array.size(t_input_arr) - 1 
    push(bar_array, barr_count + 1)
    if array.get(t_prev_arr, i) >= t_input - thresh and array.get(t_prev_arr, i) <= t_input + thresh 
        push(r_max_arr, hitoop[i])
        push(r_min_arr, optolo[i])
        push(cltoop_max_arr, cltoop[i])
        push(time_arr, time[i])
        bullish_r += array.get(bullish_arr, i) 
        bearish_r += array.get(bearish_arr, i) 
        cltoop_r += array.get(cltoop_arr, i)
        hitoop_r += array.get(hitoop_arr, i) 
        lotoop_r += array.get(optolo_arr, i) 
        piv_hi += array.get(piv_hi_arr, i)
        piv_lo += array.get(piv_lo_arr, i)
        r_hi_max := array.max(r_max_arr) 
        r_lo_max := array.max(r_min_arr) 
        r_hi_min := array.min(r_max_arr) 
        r_lo_min := array.min(r_min_arr) 
        time_r := array.get(time_arr, i)
        co_max := array.max(cltoop_max_arr) 
        co_min := array.min(cltoop_max_arr) 
        instances += 1
```

t_input represents the technical under assessment (it can range from MFI, RSI, Stoch, etc. depending on the input type). You can see I added a bar_array and barr_count to try and resolve the issue, but it didn't work.

So I tried referencing by the "time" function, with no luck, I tried timestamp, again no luck.
The one that somewhat worked was the bar_array where it would add a value for each value in the array, so it would slowly increase by one on each array stored value: (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Because the indicator is filtered out array data in the second portion of the array, the array size becomes less, only the relevant variables are being displayed, so within the bar_array, I was hoping to use it as an index of the location within the array by doing something like this:

```
label.new(bar_index - array.get(bar_array, i), High, text = "test", color = color.lime)
```

I am not really a coder and am not overly experienced with Pinescript, so I would be greatful for any help at all!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to create a label array and use that.

````
var label [] LABELARRAYMULTILABELS = array.new_label()
//FIRST LABEL
if close >= close[1]
    array.push(LABELARRAYMULTILABELS, label.new(bar_index, high, text = str.tostring(close), color= color.green))

//SECOND LABEL
if close < close[1]
    array.push(LABELARRAYMULTILABELS, label.new(bar_index, high, text = str.tostring(close), color= color.red))

//ONLY DELETE LABELS IF THEY REACH A MAX NUMBER
if array.size(LABELARRAYMULTILABELS) > 2
    label.delete(array.shift(LABELARRAYMULTILABELS))
    ```
````